# how to save customer custom attribute in database table?

Tags: magento2.4.6, php8.2

I have created one custom module, in that module I have created custom attribute, name like "**landmark**", for frontend and admin customer, this attribute display at frontend customer address section and admin customer address section, now I want to save that attribute value in 3 tables, **customer_address_entity, quote_address, sales_order_address**,

for that I have do some code,

UpgradeData.php

```
<?php

namespace My\Customfield\Setup;

use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\UpgradeDataInterface;

class UpgradeData implements UpgradeDataInterface
{
   private $customerSetupFactory;

   public function __construct(\Magento\Customer\Setup\CustomerSetupFactory $customerSetupFactory)
   {
       $this->customerSetupFactory = $customerSetupFactory;
   }

   public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
   {
       $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
       //if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1') < 0) {
       if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.2.0', '<')) {
           $customerSetup->addAttribute('customer_address', 'landmark', [
               'label' => 'Landmark',
               'input' => 'text',
               'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
               'size' => 255,
               'length' => 255,
               'source' => '',
               'required' => true,
               'position' => 90,
               'visible' => true,
               'system' => false,
               'is_used_in_grid' => false,
               'is_visible_in_grid' => false,
               'is_filterable_in_grid' => false,
               'is_searchable_in_grid' => false,
               'frontend_input' => 'text',
               'backend' => ''
           ]);

           // Get the attribute instance
           $attribute = $customerSetup->getEavConfig()
                ->getAttribute('customer_address', 'landmark');

           // Add the attribute to the necessary forms
           $attribute->setData('used_in_forms', [
                'adminhtml_customer_address',
                'adminhtml_customer',
                'customer_address_edit',
                'customer_register_address',
                'customer_address',
                'checkout_register',
                'checkout_shipping_address',
                'customer_register_edit',
                'adminhtml_checkout'
            ]);

           // Save the attribute
           $attribute->save();

           // Get the setup connection
           $connection = $setup->getConnection();

           // Add the landmark column to customer_address_entity table
           $connection->addColumn(
               $setup->getTable('customer_address_entity'),
               'landmark',
               [
                   'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                   'size' => 255,
                   'length' => 255,
                   'nullable' => true,
                   'comment' => 'Landmark'
               ]
           );

           // Add the landmark column to quote_address table
           $connection->addColumn(
               $setup->getTable('quote_address'),
               'landmark',
               [
                   'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                   'size' => 255,
                   'length' => 255,
                   'nullable' => true,
                   'comment' => 'Landmark'
               ]
           );

           // Add the landmark column to sales_order_address table
           $connection->addColumn(
               $setup->getTable('sales_order_address'),
               'landmark',
               [
                   'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                   'size' => 255,
                   'length' => 255,
                   'nullable' => true,
                   'comment' => 'Landmark'
               ]
           );
       }
   }
}
```

app/code/My/Customfield/view/frontend/layout/customer_address_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="customer_address_edit" >
           <action method="setTemplate">
              <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">
                 My_Customfield::address/edit.phtml
              </argument>
           </action>
       </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

app/code/My/Customfield/view/frontend/layout/my_customfield_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="order_info">
            <block class="My\Customfield\Block\Order\Landmark" name="my_customfield_landmark" template="My_Customfield::order/view/landmark.phtml" after="order_payment"></block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

My/Customfield/view/frontend/templates/address/edit.phtml

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var \Magento\Customer\Block\Address\Edit $block */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address $viewModel */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\Escaper $escaper */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
/** @var \Magento\Customer\ViewModel\Address\RegionProvider $regionProvider */
$viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
$regionProvider = $block->getRegionProvider();
?>
<?php $_company = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Company::class) ?>
<?php $_telephone = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Telephone::class) ?>
<?php $_fax = $block->getLayout()->createBlock(\Magento\Customer\Block\Widget\Fax::class) ?>
<?php $_country_id = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id'); ?>
<?php $_street = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('street'); ?>
<?php $_city = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city'); ?>
<?php $_region = $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('region'); ?>
<?php $_selectRegion = 'Please select a region, state or province.'; ?>
<?php $_displayAll = $block->getConfig('general/region/display_all'); ?>

<?php $_vatidValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('vat_id'); ?>
<?php $_cityValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('city'); ?>
<?php $_postcodeValidationClass_value = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('postcode'); ?>
<?php $_postcodeValidationClass = $_postcodeValidationClass_value; ?>
<?php $_streetValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('street'); ?>
<?php $_streetValidationClassNotRequired = $_streetValidationClass !== null ?
    trim(str_replace('required-entry', '', $_streetValidationClass)) : ''; ?>
<?php $_regionValidationClass = $viewModel->addressGetAttributeValidationClass('region'); ?>
<form class="form-address-edit"
      action="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getSaveUrl()) ?>"
      method="post"
      id="form-validate"
      enctype="multipart/form-data"
      data-hasrequired="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('* Required Fields')) ?>">
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Contact Information')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
        <input type="hidden" name="success_url" value="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getSuccessUrl()) ?>">
        <input type="hidden" name="error_url" value="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getErrorUrl()) ?>">
        <?= $block->getNameBlockHtml() ?>

        <?php if ($_company->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_company->setCompany($block->getAddress()->getCompany())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($_telephone->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_telephone->setTelephone($block->getAddress()->getTelephone())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

        <?php if ($_fax->isEnabled()): ?>
            <?= $_fax->setFax($block->getAddress()->getFax())->toHtml() ?>
        <?php endif ?>

    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="fieldset">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Address')) ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field street required">
            <label for="street_1" class="label"><span><?= /* @noEscape */ $_street ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <div class="field primary">
                    <label for="street_1" class="label">
                        <span>
                            <?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Street Address: Line %1', 1)) ?>
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <input type="text"
                       name="street[0]"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine(1)) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_street ?>"
                       id="street_1"
                       class="input-text <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClass) ?>"/>
                <div class="nested">
                    <?php for ($_i = 1, $_n = $viewModel->addressGetStreetLines(); $_i < $_n; $_i++): ?>
                        <div class="field additional">
                            <label class="label" for="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>">
                                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Street Address: Line %1', $_i + 1)) ?></span>
                            </label>
                            <div class="control">
                                <input type="text" name="street[<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i ?>]"
                                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine($_i + 1)) ?>"
                                       title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?>"
                                       id="street_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_i + 1 ?>"
                                       class="input-text
                                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_streetValidationClassNotRequired) ?>">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    <?php endfor; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <?php if ($viewModel->addressIsVatAttributeVisible()): ?>
            <div class="field taxvat">
                <label class="label" for="vat_id">
                    <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('vat_id') ?></span>
                </label>
                <div class="control">
                    <input type="text"
                           name="vat_id"
                           value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getVatId()) ?>"
                           title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('vat_id') ?>"
                           class="input-text <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_vatidValidationClass) ?>"
                           id="vat_id">
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="field country required">
            <label class="label" for="country">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('country_id') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <?= $block->getCountryHtmlSelect() ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field region required">
            <label class="label" for="region_id">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $_region ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <select id="region_id" name="region_id"
                        title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_region ?>"
                        class="validate-select region_id"
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ !$_displayAll ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>>
                    <option value=""><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__($_selectRegion)) ?></option>
                </select>
                <input type="text"
                       id="region"
                       name="region"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getRegion()) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $_region ?>"
                       class="input-text validate-not-number-first
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_regionValidationClass) ?>"
                        <?= !$_displayAll ? ' disabled="disabled"' : '' ?>/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field city required">
            <label class="label" for="city">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('city') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="city"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getCity()) ?>"
                       title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('City')) ?>"
                       class="input-text <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_cityValidationClass) ?>"
                       id="city">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="field zip required">
            <label class="label" for="zip">
                <span><?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?></span>
            </label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text"
                       name="postcode"
                       value="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getAddress()->getPostcode()) ?>"
                       title="<?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getAttributeData()->getFrontendLabel('postcode') ?>"
                       id="zip"
                       class="input-text validate-zip-international
                        <?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr($_postcodeValidationClass) ?>">
                <div role="alert" class="message warning">
                    <span></span>
                </div>
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag("display: none;", 'div.message.warning') ?>
            </div>
        </div>
        
    <!-- Landmark Custom Field  -->
        <div class="field">
            <label class="label" for="landmark">Landmark</label>
            <?php $landmarkAttribute = $block->getAddress()->getCustomAttribute('landmark'); ?>
            <input type="text" name="landmark" value="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($landmarkAttribute ? $landmarkAttribute->getValue() : ''); ?>"/>
        </div>
    <!-- Landmark Custom Field  -->
        
        <?php if ($block->isDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__("It's a default billing address.")) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultBilling()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set billing">
                <input type="checkbox" id="primary_billing" name="default_billing" value="1" class="checkbox">
                <label class="label" for="primary_billing">
                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default billing address')) ?></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_billing" value="1" />
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($block->isDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="message info">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__("It's a default shipping address.")) ?></span>
            </div>
        <?php elseif ($block->canSetAsDefaultShipping()): ?>
            <div class="field choice set shipping">
                <input type="checkbox" id="primary_shipping" name="default_shipping" value="1" class="checkbox">
                <label class="label" for="primary_shipping">
                    <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Use as my default shipping address')) ?></span>
                </label>
            </div>
        <?php else: ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="default_shipping" value="1">
        <?php endif; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <div class="primary">
            <button type="submit"
                    class="action save primary"
                    data-action="save-address"
                    disabled="disabled"
                    title="<?= $escaper->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Save Address')) ?>">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Save Address')) ?></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="secondary">
            <a class="action back" href="<?= $escaper->escapeUrl($block->getBackUrl()) ?>">
                <span><?= $escaper->escapeHtml(__('Go back')) ?></span>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#form-validate": {
            "addressValidation": {
                "postCodes": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getPostCodeConfig()->getSerializedPostCodes() ?>
            }
        },
        "#country": {
            "directoryRegionUpdater": {
                "optionalRegionAllowed": <?= /* @noEscape */ $_displayAll ? 'true' : 'false' ?>,
                "regionListId": "#region_id",
                "regionInputId": "#region",
                "postcodeId": "#zip",
                "form": "#form-validate",
                "regionJson": <?= /* @noEscape */ $regionProvider->getRegionJson(); ?>,
                "defaultRegion": "<?= (int) $block->getRegionId() ?>",
                "countriesWithOptionalZip": <?= /* @noEscape */ $viewModel->dataGetCountriesWithOptionalZip(true) ?>
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

My/Customfield/view/frontend/templates/order/view.phtml

```
<?php
    // Retrieve the shipping address from the order
    $shippingAddress = $_order->getShippingAddress();
    if ($shippingAddress) {
        // Retrieve the landmark attribute value
        $landmark = $shippingAddress->getCustomAttribute('landmark');
        if ($landmark) {
            // Display the landmark value
            echo "<div class='landmark'>";
            echo "<strong>Landmark:</strong> " . $block->escapeHtml($landmark->getValue());
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
?>
```

/My/Customfield/view/base/ui_component/customer_address_form.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<form xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
    <fieldset name="custom_fields">
        <field name="landmark" sortOrder="100" formElement="input">
            <settings>
                <visible>true</visible>
                <label translate="true">Landmark</label>
            </settings>
        </field>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

/My/Customfield/view/adminhtml/layout/sales_order_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <referenceBlock name="order_tab_info">
                <referenceBlock name="order_info">
                    <container name="shipping_address" as="shipping_address" label="Shipping Address" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="shipping-address order-address">
                        <block class="My\Customfield\Block\Order\View\Landmark" name="order_shipping_view_landmark" template="My_Customfield::order/view/landmark.phtml" before="-">
                            <arguments>
                                <argument name="title" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Landmark</argument>
                                <argument name="order_data" xsi:type="string">shipping_address</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </block>
                    </container>
                </referenceBlock>
            </referenceBlock>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

/My/Customfield/view/adminhtml/templates/order/view/landmark.phtml

```
<?php $landmarkAttribute = $block->getOrder()->getShippingAddress()->getCustomAttribute('landmark'); ?>
<?php if ($landmarkAttribute): ?>
    <div class="admin__field">
        <strong class="admin__field-label"><?= __('Landmark') ?>:</strong>
        <div class="admin__field-value"><?= $block->escapeHtml($landmarkAttribute->getValue()) ?></div>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this code saves the attribute value in customer_address_entity_text table not the other 3 table,
please help me with this, what mistake I do here?

Answer (score 0):

Attribute value saves into `quote_address` and `sales_order_address` during the checkout process.
Select the address from the checkout page then select the address data set in the `quote_address` table
After the quote converts into order the address data is set into the `sales_order_address` table.

Please check after place order

Comment: thanks for your answer, but in customer_address_entity table store value when customer  save the address from frontend, that is also not saves the value.

Comment: When saving the customer address from the frontend, It will not affect the quote and sales tables.

Comment: yes right, but my question is, in my code what I have done mistake, that not saved the value in customer_address_entity table after save address customer side?

Comment: Can you please check this link
 : https://www.integerbyteblog.in/magento/custom-attribute-not-saving-in-magento-2/

Comment: i have checked this, but did not understand exactly.

Comment: Check these tables   1. eav_attribute   
2. customer_eav_attribute  
3. customer_eav_attribute_website   
4. customer_form_attribute

Comment: i have checked all the tables, all tables have landmark attributes is there with id

Answer (score 0):

you can check below reference for add custom field in customer address section.

- [how to add custom field](https://blog.magezon.com/how-to-add-field-in-magento-2-checkout-page-mgt/)
- [Magento 2: How to add a custom field to checkout](https://www.magetrend.com/blog/magento-2-add-custom-checkout-field/)

Comment: i have already added custom attribute, but its value not saved in the database.